# What is this python concept called? Parent class using child-only attributes.

Tags: python, python-2.7, duck-typing

I am writing some code that is an upside down triangle of inheritance. I have a base Linux class that has a CLIENT attr which holds a connection. I have several APIs that are logically separated (kvm, yum, gdb, dhcp, etc..) that use CLIENT but I only want the user to need to create a single instance of Linux class but be able to call all the methods from the Parent classes. While maintaining the nice logical code separation among the parents:

```
class Linux(
SSHClient,
yum.Yum,
kvm.Kvm,
ldap.Ldap,
lshw.Lshw,
packet_capture.Tcpdump,
tc.TrafficControl,
networking.Networking,
gdb.Gdb,
dhcp.Dhcp,
httputil.Http,
scp.Scp,
fileutils.FileUtils):
```

I made a little example:

```
class Dad(object):
        def __init__(self):
                raise NotImplementedError("Create Baby instead")

        def dadCallBaby(self):
                print('sup {}'.format(self.babyName))

class Mom(object):
        def __init__(self):
                raise NotImplementedError("Create Baby instead")

        def momCallBaby(self):
                print('goochi goo {}'.format(self.babyName))

class Baby(Mom, Dad):
        def __init__(self, name):
                self.babyName = name

        def greeting(self):
                self.momCallBaby()
                self.dadCallBaby()

x=Baby('Joe')
x.greeting()
```

What is doing this called? Is this Duck Typing? And is there a better option?

Answer (score 3):

There's really no such thing as "child-only attributes".

The attribute `babyName` is just stored in each object's namespace, and looked up there. Python doesn't care that it happened to be stored by `Baby.__init__`. And in fact, you can write store the same attribute on a `Mom` that isn't a `Baby` and it will work the same way:

```
class NotABaby(Mom):
    def __init__(self): pass

mom = NotABaby()
mom.babyName = 'Me?'
mom.momCallBaby()
```

---

Also, it's hard to suggest a better way to do what you're doing, because what you're doing is inherently confusing and probably shouldn't be done.

Inheritance normally means subtyping—that is, `Baby` should only be a subclass of `Mom` if every `Baby` instance is usable as a `Mom`.<sup>1</sup>

But a baby is not a mom and a dad.<sup>2</sup> A baby *has* a mom and a dad. And the way to represent that is by giving `Baby` attributes for its mom and dad:

```
class Baby(object):
    def __init__(self, mom, dad, name):
        self.mom, self.dad, self.name = mom, dad, name
    def greeting(self):
        self.mom.momCallBaby(self.name)
        self.dad.dadCallBaby(self.name)
```

Notice that, e.g., this means that the same woman can be the mom of two babies. Since that's also true of the real-life thing you're modeling here, that's a sign that you're modeling things correctly.

---

Your "real" example is a little less clear, but I suspect the same thing is going on there.

The only reason you want to use inheritance, as far as I can tell, is:

> I only want the user to need to create a single instance of Linux class

You don't need, or want, inheritance for that:

```
class Linux(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ssh_client = SSHClient()
        self.yum = yum.Yum()
        # etc.
```

> … but be able to call all the methods from the Parent classes

If `yum.Yum`, `ldap.Ldap` and `dhcp.Dhcp` both have methods named `lookup`, which one would be called by `Linux.lookup`?

What you probably want is to just leave the attributes as public attributes, and use them explicitly:

```
system = Linux()
print(system.yum.lookup(package))
print(system.ldap.lookup(name))
print(system.dhcp.lookup(reservation))
```

Or you'll want to provide a "Linux API" that wraps all the underlying APIs:

```
def lookup_package(self, package):
    return self.yum.lookup(package)
def lookup_ldap_name(self, name):
    return self.ldap.lookup(name)
def lookup_reservation(self, reservation):
    return self.dhcp.lookup(reservation)
```

---

If you really do want to just forward every method of all of your different components, and you're sure that none of them conflict with each other, and there are way too many to write out manually, you can always do it programmatically, by iterating all of the classes, iterating `inspect.getmembers` of each one, filtering out the ones that start with `_` or aren't unbound methods, creating a proxy function, and `setattr`-ing it onto `Linux`.

Or, alternatively (probably not as good an idea in this case, but very commonly useful in cases that aren't that different), you can proxy dynamically, at method lookup time, by implementing a `__getattr__` method (and, often, a `__dir__` method).

I think one of these two kinds of proxying may be what you're *really* after here.

---

<sub>1. There are some cases where you want to inherit for reasons other than subtyping. For example, you inherit a mixin class to get implementations for a bunch of methods. The question of whether your class is usable wherever that mixin's instances are usable doesn't really make sense, because the mixin isn't usable anywhere (except as a base class). But the subtyping is still the standard that you're bending there.</sub>

<sub>2. If it *is*, call Child Protective Services. And also call Professor X, because that shouldn't be physically possible.</sub>

Comment: I was calling it an Orphan Class because it has a bunch of parents. But thank you very much. I did have to be careful about making sure no method names overlapped but I like the dynamic proxy.  Maybe I can make a meta class that registers all the method names and alerts me if I try to create and instance of a repeated method?

Comment: @GrantMcCloskey I don't think you need a metaclass, just a function (possibly written to be used as a decorator). If you want to get _really_ clever, you can have it generate the `__init__` and other methods—although it might be simpler to just design a decorator to be used with `@dataclass` (or `@attr.s`) that generates proxy methods for all attributes based on their types.

Comment: Looks like maybe what I need is [Proxy Classes](https://renzo.lucioni.xyz/python-proxy-classes/), Linux is the proxy class and stuff like KVM etc. Inherit from `SSHClient` where CLIENT comes from. Again, thanks for those suggestions. Always awesome to learn more about this language.